# Why is Internet speed faster in win10 virtualbox than in win10 host

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I was sandboxing an application, and as it was downloading (around 5GB) I noticed that the download rate was around 7.2MBps (57.6 Mbps), while normally, in my host, I'd download with a rate around 3.5MBps (28Mbps).

I've checked if the rate wasn't displaying wrong, but it was correct, because after timing both the VB and the host, the host was about half as slow.

I'd expect a VB to be slower, anyone have a hypothesis as to why this happened?

Should I run a VB in a VB in a VB etc? Just kidding of course, but why did this happen?

Comment: Is your host NIC running on full speed? Is it a fast Ethernet or gigabit Ethernet?

Comment: How do you have networking configured in the guest (bridge, NAT, etc.)? If bridged, is it possible the host IP is routing odd or under some network restrictions that the guest IP doesn't have?

Comment: Another possibility is that you have two disks in the PC and one is an SSD that the guest is writing the file to (vs a spinning disk for the host.) Try using an internet speed test to verify results.